# PostForObject - DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on Spring boot application,
it simply sends JSON files to a php server that reads json and inserts the data into the database.
Post Method

```
public void sendListPayload(int count, List object, String controller) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        String newSignature = "";
        Control type = Control.valueOf(controller);
        String payload = "";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = https://develop.siteonline.com.br/services/export.pl.php;
        HttpHeaders headers;
        payload = convertListToJson(object);
        headers = newGetHeaders(payload);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(payload, headers);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
                .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String answer = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
        log.info("Classe: " + type + "" + answer);
    }
```

When receiving the response Spring is throwing an exception

```
29-03-2019 17:30:48.105 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:775)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:728)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:435)
    at com.speedsoft.bws.useful.Useful.sendListPayload(Useful.java:211)
    at com.speedsoft.bws.useful.Useful.testSendListPayload(Useful.java:86)
    at com.speedsoft.bws.controller.PeriodoLetivoController.createPostPeriodo(PeriodoLetivoController.java:56)
    at com.speedsoft.bws.controller.PeriodoLetivoController.testPost(PeriodoLetivoController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Json being sent

```
[{"periodoID":12,"nomePeriodo":"2012","inicio":"2012-01-01T02:00:00Z","fim":"2012-12-31T02:00:00Z"},
{"periodoID":13,"nomePeriodo":"2013","inicio":"2013-01-01T02:00:00Z","fim":"2013-12-31T02:00:00Z"}]
```

I do not know why ... before, when the
 server was not https this did not happen, grateful to anyone who can help

Comment: Try just with  `restTemplate.postForEntity("https://develop.siteonline.com.br/services/export.pl.php", payload, String.class);` and get ResponseEntity

Comment: @NikolayHristov
a did so
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("https://develop.siteonline.com.br/services/export.pl.php", (Object) payload, String.class);
and resulted
exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
 at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97)

Comment: So you have to use postForObject and you need to use MultiValueMap for your payload parameter. Can you show your json that you are posting?

Comment: @NikolayHristov ok

Comment: Are you posting 2 objects at the same time with one request?

Comment: Multiple objects at the same time ... my list has several, I command 1 MB at a time and it works perfectly until they change the server to secure HTTPS

Comment: The status code is 500 and all 5xx codes are server errors. If it was from the request the code would be 400 like bad request or something else from 4xx errors.